# Can't open kendoui dropdown in a (asp.net mvc4) partial view loaded with jquery .load() method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, partial-views

while everythings was going fine at first dev level, I'm ranning into a problem,
I can't get a dropdrownlist from kendo ui opening inside of a partial loaded by jquery load method event,

got

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.metro.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
```

and jquery on, 
samples goes here:

```
<div class="demo-section" style="width: 250px; text-align: center;">
<label for="titles">Select Title:</label>
<input id="titles" />
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#titles").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            filter: [{
                field: "Name",
                operator: "contains",
                value: "Star Wars"
            }, {
                field: "BoxArt.SmallUrl",
                operator: "neq",
                value: null
            }],
            transport: {
                read: "http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

all of that loaded with

```
$("#mydiv").load(url)
```

For information, I got some grids working inside of the partials, but the dropdown for the editable grid got the same behavior, it does not open...

anyone got an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem locally but to no avail - the provided code works as expected.

Could you check [this test project](http://uploading.com/c2927558/DropDownListTest-zip) and let me know how it differs from your real setup?

Comment: Hi, thank for trying, I don't have <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" /> in my project, I use open source version of kendo ui.

Comment: You did well, I took off the reference and I saw all working... still can't the problem in my project :/

Answer (score 0):

reading Vladimir samples, I replaced my kendo ui reference

and magic ! just this line made this working

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

seems like the version of jquery inside of asp.net mvc template is not the right one to use

Thanks for the samples !